# WinForms drag and drop to rearrange multiple items in ListView

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

I can't figure out how to allow multiple items to be rearranged in a ListView. This is how I handle one item:

```
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent)
    {
            //get target index and other things

            if (drgevent.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem)))
            {
                ListViewItem draggedItem = (ListViewItem)drgevent.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem));
                int origIndex = draggedItem.Index;
                if (origIndex != targetIndex)
                {
                    var e = new RearrangeItemEventArgs(origIndex, targetIndex);
                    OnRearrangeItem(e);
                }
            }
    }
```

But even after enabling `MultiSelect`, `drgevent.Data` still only contains `ListViewItem` (and `WindowsForms10PersistentObject`, but I have no idea what that is).

I expected it to contain `SelectedListViewItemCollection`, `ListViewItemCollection`, or even `ListViewItem[]`, but none of them worked.

So how would I get all the selected items, and not just one of them?

Comment: What you get in the DragDrop event entirely depends on what you passed to DoDragDrop().  Which is code we cannot see.  You forgot to post its code so you probably didn't realize it mattered.  It matters.  How you expect the user to select multiple items *and* start a drag without losing the selection is also very unclear.

Comment: D'oh! I forgot about that, it's working now, thanks.